# How to record submix on android device in realtime? (if it's possible)

Tags: java, android, audiorecord

I'm trying to record a submix from device for monitoring and I have some issues with that. I'm using `AudioRecord` instance and audio source is `MediaRecorder.AudioSource.REMOTE_SUBMIX`. I found in internet information that I must use `android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT` permission but it's said "not for use by third-party apps". I tried to launch my application but it throws an exception:

```
10-14 16:26:00.619 5934 5934 E     AudioRecord com.frez.audiofx                 Could not get audio input for record source 8
10-14 16:26:00.619 5934 5934 E     AudioRecord-JNI com.frez.audiofx             Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed.
10-14 16:26:00.620 5934 5934 E     android.media.AudioRecord com.frez.audiofx     Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
10-14 16:26:00.623 5934 5964 W     dalvikvm com.frez.audiofx                    threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41632d40)
10-14 16:26:00.625 5934 5964 E     AndroidRuntime com.frez.audiofx              FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1468
10-14 16:26:00.625 5934 5964 E     AndroidRuntime com.frez.audiofx              Process: com.frez.audiofx, PID: 5934
10-14 16:26:00.625 5934 5964 E     AndroidRuntime com.frez.audiofx              java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an uninitialized AudioRecord.
10-14 16:26:00.625 5934 5964 E     AndroidRuntime com.frez.audiofx              at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:525)
10-14 16:26:00.625 5934 5964 E     AndroidRuntime com.frez.audiofx              at com.frez.audiofx.AudioThread.run(AudioThread.java:45)
```

And my question is: is it actually possible? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This API is not public to 3rd-party apps, so you need to sign your apps with platform key. if you have the platform source code, you can just add below line in your Android.mk to sign your app with platform key.

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
```

Or if you can get the platform sign key, you can sign it yourself to make it work.

Comment: Why is it not available to record one's own app, with MediaProjection?